# Was it approved or was it rejected?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

One of my [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/45216) was rejected (thinking about it, probably rightfully so). However, the page where I can see who rejected it has the following message:

[image: Rejected or approved]

Well, which one is it? Was it rejected in an approving manner? Was it approved in a disapproving tone?

<sub>This looks like something I'd see in Lotus Notes, not SO.</sub>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Stack Overflow requires multiple approvers for an edit. Thus, my conjecture is that Tom H did indeed approve your edit, but it was still in a pending state here. His approval vote appears to have been at `19:31:38Z`, which is 38 seconds after you initially proposed it.

However, the question got closed as a duplicate at `19:33:40Z`, which means that Community makes an auto-revision. Since there's now a higher revision than yours, which generally doesn't happen on account of the whole edit-lock thing, your edit suggestion got discarded as a rejection.

So, the suggestion was indeed on the road to approval, up until it was effectively hit by a crossing train before it reached its destination. As it never arrived, it could not be fully approved, and must be rejected even though the paperwork wasn't in order.

Comment: It's a good explanation (probably the right one), but the message is confusing as hell. It might be better to add the Community user's vote to the summary just to clear things up.

Comment: @alex I think in this scenario, Community didn't vote so much as trample you to dust. [A similar thing happened here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/841), and the rejected user didn't even get a record of what happened (the question was migrated before any approvals). I think adding that to the summary is a very valid feature request.

Comment: So, where might such a feature request be?

Comment: @SamB It may not have been proposed yet.